# Exercise with C++ function to identify prime numbers using !=

Tags: c++, function, codeblocks, primes

I am working my way through the book c++ programming principles and practice. In the book there is an exercise to find prime numbers by checking a number against numbers that have been identified as primes. This is the function I wrote to solve this problem.

```
vector <int> primes;

int findprime (int x) {
    for (int p=0; p<primes.size(); ++p) {
        if (x%primes[p]!=0) {
            return x;
        }
    }   
}

int main() {
    primes.push_back(2);
    for (int i=3; i<100; ++i) {
        primes.push_back(findprime(i));
    }
    for (int i=0; i<primes.size(); ++i) {
        cout << primes[i] << '\n'; 
    }
}
```

The authors function in his solution is:

```
bool is_prime(int n) {
    for (int p = 0; p<prime.size(); ++p)
        if (n%prime[p]==0) return false;    // no remainder: prime[p] divided

    return true;    // no smaller prime could divide
}
```

My code doesn't work but I don't really understand why. I think I am missing some knowledge on exactly how the functions operate. I would really appreciate it if someone would explain the reason my code doesn't work and fill in my blanks.

Comment: You getting any error or results are wrong?

Comment: My result is wrong. Puts every number between 1-100 into the vector. I think what's happening is even through I have specified the function only returns the value if its != it returns the value regardless. I believe I have a slight misunderstanding on how the functions operate and hope someone with experience can explain.

Answer (score 2):

You are invoking undefined behavior by reaching the end of a function defined to return a value without returning anything.  Your compiler should have issued a warning.  If it didn't then you should turn on compiler warnings.

`findprime` always returns some `int`, but if `x` is not evenly divisible by one of the values in `primes` then you will reach the end of the function without ever encountering a `return` statement.  What's it supposed to return in that case?  The answer is that the answer is unspecified.  The implementation is free to do whatever it wants in that case.  In this case it seems it's just returning `x`.

Comment: Do you know what option needs enabling in code-blocks to get the relevant compiler warning?

Comment: I'm not sure where to set compiler flags in code-blocks, but I think it uses g++ as its compiler.  If that's the case you want the `-Wreturn-type` flag in this case.  I would recommend `-Wall`, which turns on most warnings, including the `-Wreturn-type` warnings.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the cleaned up code, annotated with the bugs and fixes [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup]:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
std::vector <int> primes;

// NOTE/BUG: before this was returning the inverse sense
// RETURNS: 0=not prime, 1=prime
int
findprime(int x)
{
    for (int p = 0; p < primes.size(); ++p) {
        if (x % primes[p] == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    // BUG: this return was missing
    return 1;
}

int
main()
{
    primes.push_back(2);

    for (int i = 3; i < 100; ++i) {
        // BUG: before this was _always_ adding the number
#if 0
        primes.push_back(findprime(i));
#else
        if (findprime(i))
            primes.push_back(i);
#endif
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < primes.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << primes[i] << '\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yours and the Author's solutions are different:

Author's logic is to check for primality of some number `n`. It does this by exiting early if any prime evenly divides `n`, and only after checking all primes concluding `true`.

What your code `int findprime (int x)` does is not this. It returns `x`, if `x` cannot be evenly divided at least one existing prime. Because it categorically adds every number as prime due to this, it can always find some number that cannot divide `x` perfectly. And as others have mentioned the function is written poorly because it can branch in a way as to avoid all `return` statements (bad, leads to undefined behavior).

I suggest using the Author's version and studying why it works - it works because when it does exit early, it does so with certainty. Not being able to be divided by a prime does not itself guarantee you're dealing with a prime, it's when *all* primes do not divide your number - ergo if *any* can divide then the number is not prime and no need to check any further. There are more advanced tests but primality testing and finding primes is its own topic to research beyond specifics to any programming language or method.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

```
int findprime(int x)
{
    for (int p=0; p<primes.size(); p++)
    {
        if ((x%primes[p])==0)
        {
           return -1;
           break;
        }
    }
return x;
}

int main()
{
   primes.push_back(2);
   primes.push_back(3);
   for (int i=3; i<100; ++i)
   {
      if(findprime(i)!=-1)  
      {
        primes.push_back(i);
      }
   }
   for (int i=0; i<primes.size(); ++i)
   {
       cout << primes[i] << '\n'; 
   }
}
```

As in one of the answer it is described above. You are going through all the values of vectors and not returning anything in the end.